# How to connect to wifi using nmcli with a static IP address and password?

Tags: linux, command-line, nmcli

There is info on how to connect to ethernet(eth0) with nmcli using a static IP, but nothing on how to connect to wifi (wlan0)?
This sets up a connection profile but how to add the password and actually bring up the connection?

```
nmcli con add con-name "mySSID" ifname wlan0 type wifi ssid "mySSID" ip4 192.168.100.101
```

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: The following is only guaranteed to work with nmcli v1.22 (because that's what version I have), the latest is probably very similar but, in my case there's a random `--` required; it is in the documentation specified for that command. Check your version with `nmcli -v` then check the specific documentation here [>>Network Manager](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/) (after you click your version click the nmcli link)

I.e., for [Version 1.2](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/1.2/nmcli.html)

`nmcli con add con-name "&%TEST%&" type wifi ifname mlan0 ssid "&%SSIDNAME%&" -- wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk wifi-sec.psk "&%PASSPHRASE%&" ipv4.method manual ipv4.address 192.168.1.51/16 ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8,8.8.8.4 ipv4.gateway 192.168.1.1`

Then

`nmcli con up "&%TEST%&"`

However, it may be more wise to ignore the con-name because you can have multiple connections with the same name.  (Luckily `nmcli con delete "&%TEST%&` deletes all of those at once!)

You could use the uuid instead.

find it by `nmcli con show`
then connect using

`nmcli con up uuid 1c86c960-8533-11e7-bb31-be2e44b06b34`
(*your uuid will not be the same...)